# react-jsonschema-form custom element position

Tags: reactjs, jsonschema, react-jsonschema-forms

Using `react-jsonschema-form` [1] we can dynamically render `React` components from configuration rather than code. I.e.

```
const Form = JSONSchemaForm.default;
const schema = {
  title: "Test form",
  type: "object",
  properties: {
    name: {
      type: "string"
    },
    age: {
      type: "number"
    }
  }
};

ReactDOM.render((
  <Form schema={schema} />
), document.getElementById("app"));
```

And we can use `uiSchema` object to customize and configure the individual look of each component. Is it possible however, instead of having the form created in a linear fashion, can I obtain each individual element and position them where I want?

For example, I may want the `name` field on `page1` and the `age` field on `page3`. The only way I can think to do this currently is editing the package's source to return individual elements rather than wrapping them into the `Form` object.

Maybe there is some way in `React` to interrogate and extract the individual components from the `Form` object?

Thanks

[1] https://react-jsonschema-form.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: As per the component’s linked documentation, it’s target use-case is the generation of forms that you don’t know the contents of. If you know all possible fields (in order to split it into meaningful pages), that goes beyond the component’s intended scope. However, if you also control the schema generation, maybe consider producing separate schemas for each form page.

Comment: I get the point of it being dynamically generated, but for instance, if I wanted to rap the resultant components into a `react-native-swiper` object (https://github.com/leecade/react-native-swiper), this component requires child View objects, which somewhere inside the `Form` object, this would exist. I guess what I would want to do is actually pull out the forms internal `View` objects so I can manipulate them.

Comment: Since this a very specific to this component, you might be best served by contacting the maintainers of that component/library directly.

Comment: Regardless of the component, I think it would be good to know how to directly manipulate the underlying components rendered via `jsonschema`

Comment: That’s completely dependent on the component. I don’t see how there could be a satisfying generic answer.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I made much sense there. The most satisfying generic response would be informing me (if its possible) to grab the underlying dynamically created View components which contains each individual form element. If I can do that, I can do what I want with the actual form elements in terms of positioning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there isn't a way to get `rjsf` to split a form into multiple UI components. You can emulate that behavior by making multiple forms (multiple JSON Schema `schema`s). Depending on the structure of the combined output you want, it may be simplest to break the `schema` down by different nested property apparent at the root level, e.g. the 1st page corresponds to the 1st key at the root level (`name`), the 2nd page corresponds to the 2nd key (`age`), and so on. Note that you'd have to control this pagination and navigation yourself, and also merge each page's `formData` back into the singular payload you were expecting.

Here's a rough draft:

```
pageOneSchema = {
  title: "Test form pg. 1",
  type: "object",
  properties: {
    name: {
      type: "string"
    }
  }
};

pageTwoSchema = {
  title: "Test form pg. 2",
  type: "object",
  properties: {
    age: {
      type: "number"
    }
  }
};

const schemas = [pageOneSchema, pageTwoSchema];

// Your component's member functions to orchestrate the form and its "pages"
state = {
  currentPage: 0,
  pages: new Array(schemas.length).fill({}), // initial pages array to empty objects = unfilled forms
}

pageDataChangeHandler = (page) => {
  const onChange = (e) => {
    const pages = [...this.state.pages];
    pages[page] = e.formData; // not too 100% about the key
    this.setState({
      pages,
    });
  }
}

getSubmitHandlerForPage = (page) => {
  if (page !== schemas.length) {
    // If current page is not the last page, move to next page
    this.setState({
      currentPage: page + 1,
    });
  } else {
    // concat all the pages' data together to recompose the singular payload
  }
}

...
const { currentPage } = this.state; 
<Form
  formData={this.state.pages[currentPage]}
  schema={schemas[currentPage]}
  onChange={this.pageDataChangeHandler(currentPage)}
  onSubmit={this.getSubmitHandlerForPage(currentPage)}
/>
```

You can also [pass children into the Form component to render your own buttons](https://react-jsonschema-form.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api-reference/form-props/#children) (so maybe you don't want the forms saying "Submit" instead of "Next Page" if they're not actually going to submit).

Note that if you do custom buttons and make a "Next" button, it must still be of "submit" type because of the type of event it emits (used for validation and some other things). Though there was an ask to [make the text/title of the submit button easier to manipulate](https://github.com/rjsf-team/react-jsonschema-form/issues/1093)...